# Python script - sliding images to compose a video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a script/library where I can create a video similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXit8kxCCTg&ab_channel=KurtHugoSchneider? Instead of having videos compose the timeline, I would like to have images that I have saved under a specific folder. The images do not need to be in a tiled format such as can be seen in the video. All images will have the same dimension and will be positioned side by side.

Ideally, it would be nice to control the velocity of the timeline (including the direction the images move in).

Thank you in advance!
Ben

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you need warpAffine https://forum.opencv.org/t/creating-video-with-movement-from-images/5838/2?u=crackwitz